# Android, for JNI should System.loadLibrary be called in an InputMethodService?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

When sub-classing `InputMethodService` where native code is used, Android will kill the service when the input method is dismissed.

Later, Android will restart the service and JNI is not present causing Java unable to find the native functions and an exception thrown.

I had previously thought that only one `System.loadLibrary` in `MainActivity` was required. Should this be added to services too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extra cost in putting LoadLibrary in all relevant classes, so go for it. Use it in static constructors of each Java class, or companion object of Kotlin class

MainActivity is not the best choice to begin with, because every time you later add another activity or service that can be started independently, you must not forget to duplicate your LoadLibrary.

Comment: Hey thanks. I have added loadLibrary and it works.Looks like Android can load only the java classes for services and leave the rest behind, so multiple static constructors are needed.

Comment: Absolutely so. You cannot control which classes will be loaded and in which order (except for the natural Java class dependencies).